# Relation between tables in different schemas in django with postgresql

Tags: python, django, postgresql, python-2.7, schema

I'm working with Django 1.9 with Postgresql and I stuck in a problem with relations between tables in different schemas.

The problem that I'm facing is that I have a table, for example, named `product`, which is in a schema named `dataflex` and another table named `client_product_sale_stx` in another schema.

When I try to migrate a relation between `client_product_sale_stx` and `product`, I got this error:

```
Applying armazem.0077_clientproductsalestx_setor_id...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 350, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 342, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 348, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 399, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 200, in handle
executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 92, in migrate
self._migrate_all_forwards(plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 121, in _migrate_all_forwards
state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 198, in apply_migration
state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 90, in __exit__
self.execute(sql)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 110, in execute
cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in execute
return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 95, in __exit__
six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: ERRO:  syntax error at or near "dataflex"
LINE 1: ...CONSTRAINT "client_product_setor_id_52aad07a_fk_"dataflex"....
```

After sometime trying to figure It out a solution for this problem, I tried to change the schemas's name to just `df` instead of `dataflex` and It worked perfectly.

I also tried to decreased table's name, and It worked just like when I decreased schema's name size, so this is most likely a problem with big constraints names.

Is this same problem with djando and postgresql big names on relation between diffent schemas?

Is there any other way to fix It? Because I'll probably need to have tables with bigger names, and I can't decrease schema's name size even more.

*`setor_id` is the name of the field of the relation in `client_product_sale_stx` model/table.
`product` model/table does not have a field for the relation.*